# getSnippet.getDescription() returns null

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i'm using the latest youtube api (v3) and am trying to extract the description from a video, it however keeps returning null. I'm using the same code as the examples (https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/MyUploads.java).

i modified it slightly to accept a random PlaylistID and display the Description rather than the Title in the function PrettyPrint().

image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqyKz.png

Comment: Could you post your code so we can see your modifications?

Comment: @jlmcdonald like is said, just prints the description....... http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/bte7zwz.png

Comment: Sorry ... the link you provided just goes to a blank page; I had to use just the imgur.com URL to get your snapshot. Anyway, on the surface the code looks correct; could you provide a playlistID that, when you run your code, returns null descriptions? That way I can see if it reproduces here.

Comment: i feel really dumb now, i used the examples as a template and forgot it restricts what it's requesting. It doesn't request the description and that was why it kept returning null. `playlistItemRequest.setFields(
                    "items(contentDetails/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/publishedAt,snippet/description),nextPageToken,pageInfo");` you made me think and fix it. I will try to build my own code in the future. thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out ... sometimes all it takes is just talking about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i forgot to edit the example's `setField();` method and didn't request the description. and thus if i did later on it would always return `null`. code fix: `playlistItemRequest.setFields(
                    "items(contentDetails/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/publishedAt,snippet/description),nextPageToken,pageInfo");`